# Get the persistence-unit name

Tags: java, jpa, toplink

How do you get the name of a persistence-unit in Java? I have a persistence.xml with many units, so I want to control which unit is used to create my EntityManager.

There's method like `getPersistenceName` or `smth`? I have searched for a while but did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this thread:
[Finding the current persistence unit for the current EntityManagerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014925/finding-the-current-persistence-unit-for-the-current-entitymanagerfactory)